# d3.js How can I make an "infinite" background grid?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, grid

I am trying to do a dragable and zoomable graph with a grid in the background, similar to this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708

However, if you start to move the background in the example you can see the end of the grid pretty quick.
Is there a posibility in d3.js to make this background grid seem infinite?

Comment: Here's my thought. Make the background in its own separate `g` element. On drag, since you know the box size, you'd move the circles normally but the background by `<transform x> mod <boxsize>`. This way when the user moves a full box length, it will reset back to the initial position seamlessly (may require some fiddling with to get perfect), effectively simulating infinite behaviour. For zoom, you'll also have to take the scale factor into account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, all you have to do is make the zoom offset a modulus of the box size. Here's a simple [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3075pd4/) without overflowing so you can see the behaviour in action. The important part is changing `d3.event.translate` to:

```
d3.event.translate[0]%(boxSize*d3.event.scale)+","+d3.event.translate[1]%(boxSize*d3.event.scale)
```

Which offsets by x mod boxsize and y mod boxsize, where boxsize is scaled by the zoom scale.

To make the transition seamless, all you have to do is make the lines draw `boxWidth` outside of the visible frame. This
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3075pd4/2/) shows this in action, and you can see it is a 'seamless' grid from one that is draw only slightly larger than the viewing frame (you can confirm this by changing the minimum zoom to 0.5 and zooming out).

On that note, if you want to allow the user to zoom out less than the original scale you'll have to divide the range of the array by the minimum zoom and similarly divide the width and height of the lines by the same factor.